# Regex patterns to extract information from event logs

Tags: regex, python-3.x, loops

I am working on an event log data, as we all know its unstructured data and need to extract important pieces of information from these logs for a better visualization perspective. This data is tab-separated, I have created a data frame from these event logs and also expected output. Col name `Event_message` is the raw event log message, and the columns `CtrJb_ID`, `Prcs_ID`, `LotID`, `Wafer_ID` are the columns which I would like to extract the information from these logs. If the condition is not met, then I would like the row to be None or empty. For example in one event if the lot id exists then extract the lot id and if not then None.

```
data = {'Timestamp':['2009/8/22 08:02:29.862', '2009/8/22 08:02:30.706','2008/08/22 08:02:33.207','2008/08/22 08:02:37.551'], 
       'Event_Message':["2009/8/22 08:02:29.862 2009/8/22 08:02:29.862  123456  ControlJobStateTransition1  CWControlJobManager 'ControlJob named XYZ12345-20090822-0005 was created and is in the QUEUED state.'   []  ['EventVariable ControlJobID    0   true    XYZ12345-20090822-0005''    ControlJobID'   'EventVariable  DataCollectionPlan  0   true    ",
                        "2009/8/22 08:02:30.706 2009/8/22 08:02:30.315  123456  PRJobStateChange    XYZ12ProcessJobManager  'Process Job 200908221102-2R34567.000-01 has changed state to PRJOBACTIVE/SETUP.'   []  ['EventVariable ProcessJobID    0   true    ''200908221102-2R34567.000-01'' ProcessJobID'   'EventVariable  ProcessJobState 0   true    ''1''",
                        "2008/08/22 08:02:33.207    2008/08/22 08:02:33.175 123456789   DAExtendPerResourceDAWaferCenterOffsetB TransferChamberSlotValvePM4 'DAPerResource EXTEND'  []  ['StatusVariable    Source  0   true    ''TransferChamber-EndEffector2''    Source' 'StatusVariable Destination 0   true    ''PM4'' Destination'    'StatusVariable WaferID 0   true    ''1A234568ABC2''    WaferID'    'StatusVariable LotID   0   true    ''200908221036-2R34567.000-01'' LotID'",
                        "2008/08/22 08:02:37.551    2008/08/22 08:02:37.404 12345678    RecipeStarted   PM4 'Started processing recipe AB0-Z-65XYZ-ABCDE12XYZ1-2R34567000 on material 1A234568ABC2. '   []  ['StatusVariable    RecipeName  0   true    ''PM4-P-14LPP-PEBNS31JFA1-8R91721000''  RecipeName' 'StatusVariable MaterialID  0   true    ''1A234568ABC2''    MaterialID' 'StatusVariable JobID   0   true    ''201910021036-2R34567.000-01'' JobID'  'EventVariable  WacID   0   true    ''''    WacID'  'StatusVariable LotID   0   true    ''2R34567.000'' LotID'  'StatusVariable SlotID  0   true    ''11"],
       'CtrJb_ID': ['XYZ12345-20090822-0005', None, None, None],
       'Prcs_ID': [None, '200908221102-2R34567.000', None, None],
       'LotID': [None, None, '200908221036-2R34567.000-01', '2R34567.000'],
       'Wafer_ID': [None, None, '1A234568ABC2', None ]}

df= pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I have read this event log message line by line and then tried to extract it using regex patterns, but not been succesful. Below is the code, that I have tried so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
f = open ("C:\ABCD\XYZ\egfh_ijk_lmn\log2009082212.txt")
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    print (line)


lot= re.compile(r'LotID\s+\d\s+\w+\s+(.*)\s+LotID')

for line in lines:
    if lot.search(str(line)):
        print(lot)
    else:
        print(None)
```

Output:

```
None
None
None
None
None
re.compile('LotID\\s+\\d\\s+\\w+\\s+(.*)\\s+LotID')
re.compile('LotID\\s+\\d\\s+\\w+\\s+(.*)\\s+LotID')
None
None
None
None
None
re.compile('LotID\\s+\\d\\s+\\w+\\s+(.*)\\s+LotID')
None
None
re.compile('LotID\\s+\\d\\s+\\w+\\s+(.*)\\s+LotID')
```

Comment: `lines` is a list, `re.findall` expects a string.

Comment: Its just an example, but if I want to create the data frame similar to above, how would I go about it?

Comment: Your `data` looks structured to me. How about you show us a line from the actual file, the regex you've tried, what you expected it to give you and what it actually gave you.

Comment: actual text message is the in the colum name Event_message, one row represents one event message. Thats the raw data, I am making an effort to get it structured, so we do some visualization.

Comment: OK so now it's matching. But you are printing out the regular expression! You need something like `m=lot.match(str(line)); print m.group();`

Comment: I am getting an error. Could you please give me a working snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Since you ask for a working snippet:

```
import re
test = "2008/08/22 08:02:33.207    2008/08/22 08:02:33.175 123456789   DAExtendPerResourceDAWaferCenterOffsetB TransferChamberSlotValvePM4 'DAPerResource EXTEND'  []  ['StatusVariable    Source  0   true    ''TransferChamber-EndEffector2''    Source' 'StatusVariable Destination 0   true    ''PM4'' Destination'    'StatusVariable WaferID 0   true    ''1A234568ABC2''    WaferID'    'StatusVariable LotID   0   true    ''200908221036-2R34567.000-01'' LotID'"
lot = re.compile(r"LotID[^']+''([\d\-.A-Z]*)''[^']+LotID")
match = lot.search(test)
if (match):
    print(match.group(1))
else:
    print "None"
```

Output:

```
200908221036-2R34567.000-01
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use look-ahead and look-behind for this sort of task. Not using them allows you to use quantifiers. In your version `\w....` will not match 'true'. Also your sample contains spaces instead of tab characters, I don't know if that is the formatting on this site or your actual data.

This will match your sample:

```
LotID\s+\d\s+\w+\s+(.*)\s+LotID
```

Though if you know what characters you expect in the Lot ID it might be better expressed as

```
LotID[^']+(['\d\-R.]*)[^']+LotID
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, in the second part, it's usually a unique number which contains numbers and alphabets. So, I tried to put in this [A-Z0-9]. But doesnt work for me. I will try different ways using your pattern and will get back to you. Thank you

Comment: >> I tried to put in this [A-Z0-9].  That won't work, even your examples contain more than numbers and letters, there are dots and minus signs as well. And you will have to include the quotes, either inside or outside the capture.

Comment: I am getting invalid syntax from this code,  lot= re.compile(r'LotID[^']+(['\d\A-Z.]*)[^']+LotID')

Comment: Yes, surely you can see why? The regular expression has single quotes in it and you've tried to surround it with single quotes.